# http post using json in java error

Tags: java, json

There is a challenge with two steps.
First do the Get on this url

```
http://mkpartners.force.com/services/apexrest/careers
```

by adding three field name, lastname, and email

```
http://mkpartners.force.com/services/apexrest/careers?firstName=Izak&lastName=Tarashandegan&email=izaktarashandegan@gmail.com
```

I did that part
and second part is to the post on this url that I constructed and past on my resume as a json file to that url, but I got 400 http  error and I cannot understand why?

this is my code for

```
package posthttp;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
/**
 *
 * @author Izak
 */
public class PostHTTP {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
            "http://mkpartners.force.com/services/apexrest/careers?firstName=Izak&lastName=Tarashandegan&email=izaktarashandegan@gmail.com");
                String json = "{\"application\":{\"isTest\":true,\"firstName\":\"Izak\",\"lastName\":\"Tarashandegan\",\"email\":\"izaktarashandegan@gmail.com\",\"phone\":\"4244420591\",\"zipcode\":\"90035\",\"describeYourself\":\"I am passionate about programming.I do my best to learn new materials about programming everyday. My favorite language is Java, and I do all my coding in Java.\",\"skills\":\"I can talk in English and Farsi fluently, and I know a little Spanish too\",\"education\":[{\"school\":\"CSUN\",\"graduationYear\":2013,\"degree\":\"bachelor\",\"major\":\"CS\"},{\"school\":\"SMC\",\"graduationYear\":2010,\"degree\":\"AA\",\"major\":\"CS\"}],\"experience\":[{\"company\":\"Ambient Digital Media\",\"fromDate\":\"2004-02-01\",\"toDate\":\"2004-05-01\",\"title\":\"web desinger\",\"workDone\":\"update their website\"},{\"company\":\"liberty plumbing and heating Inc.\",\"fromDate\":\"2004-06-01\",\"toDate\":\"2013-05-15\",\"title\":\"web desinger\",\"workDone\":\"work as a book keeper\"}]}";
        StringEntity input = new StringEntity(json);
        input.setContentType("application/json");
        postRequest.setEntity(input);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }
    }

}
```

the issue that i have is it gives me error http error code 400, but i follow everything as far as i know. 
the exact error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400
at posthttp.PostHTTP.main(PostHTTP.java:41)
```

Java Result: 1

if more information is needed, i am more than happy to provide

Comment: Your URL looks like its trying to use parameters, but there is no `?` separator in it

Comment: good point, and I realize it so I added it, but I still get the same error. I should get 202 as right answer

Comment: Well, a 404 is basically that the URL is not found - thats what I'd focus your investigation on for trying to solve it. Perhaps there is another typo, or something else.

Comment: @Roman, using the get service was for the first step. Here I have to use POST service.

Comment: @Chris ,I have done what I was able to think and found, but I could not find how to correct this. Could you be kind and help ?

Comment: 400 is a Bad Request, not missing URL. There is something wrong with either your json or the transmission protocol (HTTP headers, message body). As a sanity test you should save your json to a file, then open it to make sure it actually appears the way you believe it should. Then look at libraries that implement HTTP transmission and see how they set headers etc. There is more to HTTP than the message body (devhub.fm/http-requestresponse-basics/). Although, if you are using the http library properly which it looks like you are at first glance, it seems likely that its a json formatting error.

Comment: Are you required to use Java? This is really simple to solve with html/jQuery. Would take about 5 mins to code and guaranteed to work since its done on bajillions of websites every day. Otherwise study the Java functions you are using since even on SO no one will do that in depth for your whole program.

Comment: @jm0 not really. could plz help me to solve in anyway you can? it is important to me cuz I can get an interview for solving it. I'm out of job for seven months and it is bad. plz if u can help me, plz do

Comment: @jm0 the irony is I used puTTy to solve this, and I get the same error

Comment: Kick, check my latest code, it works now, you had omitted sending skills as a JSON list

Comment: it worked. 
wowwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
but what happened?
Can you explain so I can learn it?

Comment: 1) your json syntax was invalid 2) your api required you to send skills as a list than as a single string. In the future try to construct the JSON object using some api nother as a literal string, it is too error prone. Look at my code example, there you can see how to read the actual HTTP response body for your request.

Comment: never mind, I understood where my issue was. 
THank you again. 
you really make someone happy with your action and god bless you.
thank you :)
but how did you find out that it has to be a list cuz I did not give your the json shema?

Comment: @loskit, could you tell me how u found out that my syntax was invalid because I didn't give you a json schema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the last closing `}`. Also, when I did the POST, i got the response:

```
[{"errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR","message":"Expected LIST<String> but found \"   I can talk in English and Farsi fluently, and I know a little Spanish too\"
```

So, you need to send JSON list there, instead of a single entry.

```
String json = "http://mkpartners.force.com/services/apexrest/careers?firstName=Izak&lastName=Tarashandegan&email=izaktarashandegan@gmail.com";
data = "{\"application\":{\"isTest\":true,\"firstName\":\"Izak\",\"lastName\":\"Tarashandegan\",\"email\":\"izaktarashandegan@gmail.com\",\"phone\":\"4244420591\",\"zipcode\":\"90035\",\"describeYourself\":\"I am passionate about programming.I do my best to learn new materials about programming everyday. My favorite language is Java, and I do all my coding in Java.\",\"skills\":[\"I can talk in English and Farsi fluently, and I know a little Spanish too\"],\"education\":[{\"school\":\"CSUN\",\"graduationYear\":2013,\"degree\":\"bachelor\",\"major\":\"CS\"},{\"school\":\"SMC\",\"graduationYear\":2010,\"degree\":\"AA\",\"major\":\"CS\"}],\"experience\":[{\"company\":\"Ambient Digital Media\",\"fromDate\":\"2004-02-01\",\"toDate\":\"2004-05-01\",\"title\":\"web desinger\",\"workDone\":\"update their website\"},{\"company\":\"liberty plumbing and heating Inc.\",\"fromDate\":\"2004-06-01\",\"toDate\":\"2013-05-15\",\"title\":\"web desinger\",\"workDone\":\"work as a book keeper\"}]}}";
```

New response:

`"Your TEST POST is correct, please set the isTest (Boolean) attribute on the application to FALSE to actually apply.`"

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
/**
 *
 * @author Izak
 */
public class PostHTTP {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
            "http://mkpartners.force.com/services/apexrest/careers?firstName=Izak&lastName=Tarashandegan&email=izaktarashandegan@gmail.com");
                String json = "{\"application\":{\"isTest\":true,\"firstName\":\"Izak\",\"lastName\":\"Tarashandegan\",\"email\":\"izaktarashandegan@gmail.com\",\"phone\":\"4244420591\",\"zipcode\":\"90035\",\"describeYourself\":\"I am passionate about programming.I do my best to learn new materials about programming everyday. My favorite language is Java, and I do all my coding in Java.\",\"skills\":[\"I can talk in English and Farsi fluently, and I know a little Spanish too\"],\"education\":[{\"school\":\"CSUN\",\"graduationYear\":2013,\"degree\":\"bachelor\",\"major\":\"CS\"},{\"school\":\"SMC\",\"graduationYear\":2010,\"degree\":\"AA\",\"major\":\"CS\"}],\"experience\":[{\"company\":\"Ambient Digital Media\",\"fromDate\":\"2004-02-01\",\"toDate\":\"2004-05-01\",\"title\":\"web desinger\",\"workDone\":\"update their website\"},{\"company\":\"liberty plumbing and heating Inc.\",\"fromDate\":\"2004-06-01\",\"toDate\":\"2013-05-15\",\"title\":\"web desinger\",\"workDone\":\"work as a book keeper\"}]}}";
        StringEntity input = new StringEntity(json);
        input.setContentType("application/json");
        postRequest.setEntity(input);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = 
                   new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()), 65728);
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }


System.out.println("finalResult " + sb.toString());
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Loskit, I added what you said, and still get the same result which is 400 HTTp error.
I realized another question to ask where this data variable goes?

Comment: read what the API tells you as the error message besides the error code? print out `response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase()`

Comment: it does not give any useful info just 400 http error code. what i got is 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400
 at posthttp.PostHTTP.main(PostHTTP.java:41)
Java Result: 1

Comment: @loskit, so what message it gave you?

Comment: maybe you ought to try it yourself...
`➜  ~  java -classpath "/home/uku/lib/httpcore-4.3.jar:/home/uku/lib/httpclient-4.3.1.jar:./home/uku/lib/httpcore-4.3.jar:/home/uku/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:." PostHTTP
finalResult "Your TEST POST is correct, please set the isTest (Boolean) attribute on the application to FALSE to actually apply."
OK
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 200
`

Comment: it works and you do not know how much I am thankful for your help because of your help, I get and job interview.
but could you plz tell me how you fixed it so I can learn?

Answer (score 2):

Using [this online json syntax validator](http://jsonlint.com/), it appears that your json string is missing a "}" at the end. You should terminate your json like this `... work as a book keeper\"}]}}"`

---

BTW, you can use [the Gson library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson) to parse json from POJOs.